# Detect mixed-case words in an if statement

Tags: java, if-statement, case-sensitive

Ok so I'm trying to write a program that prints certain messages when the input contains a certain word in a certain case.

For example, if the word is orange, the program would detect that the word orange is in the input, and then say something depending on whether it exists, is lower case, or is upper case. As far as all that goes, I'm good, the only thing I can't figure out is how to make it detect the word when it's in mixed case, like oRange, or oranGe.

Comment: toLowerCase comes to mind.

Comment: Depending on whether you need to support unicode surrogate pairs, one of [`Character.isUpperCase(char))`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Character.html#isUpperCase(char)) or [`Character.isUpperCase(int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Character.html#isUpperCase(int)) may also be useful for implementing such a function.

Comment: Hi, if my answer is helpful, please flag it as accepted (the green check mark)

Answer (score 0):

I think this would do it:

```
if (!yourString.toLowerCase().equals(yourString) && !yourString.toUpperCase().equals(yourString)) {
    mixed = true
}
```

Comment: or equalsIgnoreCase. String is funny that way :)

Comment: @Stultuske - I don't see how that would tell if it is mixed case with fewer comparisons?

Comment: it wouldn't, but then again, that's not the requirement. "orange" should return true when the test String is either "orange" or "oRaNgE"

Comment: "Detect mixed-case words". Source: The headline

Answer (score 0):

You can utilize a method to see if a particular string is mixed case, for example:

```
public static boolean isMixedCase (final String inputString) {
    if (inputString == null || inputString.isEmpty()) {
        return false;
    }
    Character c;
    boolean hasUpper = false;
    boolean hasLower = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < inputString.length(); i++) {
        c = inputString.charAt(i);
        if (Character.isUpperCase(c)) {
            hasUpper = true;
        }
        else if (Character.isLowerCase(c)) {
            hasLower = true;
        }
    }
    return hasLower && hasUpper;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this method to check all the cases: identical, lower-case, upper-case, mixed-case.

```
public class TestCase
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "orange";
        String strInput = "oRange";

        System.out.println(testCase(str, strInput));
    }

    public static int testCase(String str, String strInput) {
        // identical
        if(str.equals(strInput)) {
            return 1;
        }

        // all lower-case
        if(str.toLowerCase().equals(strInput)) {
            return 2;
        }

        // all upper-case
        if(str.toUpperCase().equals(strInput)) {
            return 3;
        }

        // mixed-case
        if(str.equalsIgnoreCase(strInput)) {
            return 4;
        }

        // not present
        return 0;
    }
}
```

For example, to check if a string is mixed-case:

```
if(testCase(str, strInput) == 4) {
    // mixed-case
}
```

Since `testCase` is *static*, you can also use it outside of this class.

Answer (score 0):

From your question, it is not entirely clear what your exact requirement is.

If you want to detect whether a string matches another, regardless of case, you could just use `String::equalsIgnoreCase`:

```java
return input.equalsIgnoreCase("orange");
```

Otherwise, I assume a string in mixed case is when it contains at least one uppercase and one lowercase character.

Well, there are many options:

1. `Character::toUpperCase` and `Character::toLowerCase`

   ```java
   var lower = false;
   var upper = false;
   for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
       char c = input.charAt(i);
       if (Character.isUpperCase(c)) {
           upper = true;
       }
       else if (Character.isLowerCase(c)) {
           lower = true;
       }

       if (lower && upper) {
           return true;
       }
   }
   return false;
   ```
2. `String::toUpperCase` and `String::toLowerCase`

   ```java
   return !(input.equals(str.toLowerCase()) || input.equals(str.toUpperCase()));
   ```
3. `Pattern::matches`

   ```java
   boolean upper = Pattern.compile("[A-Z]").matcher(input).find();
   boolean lower = Pattern.compile("[a-z]").matcher(input).find();
   return upper && lower;
   ```

In the abovementioned code, I assumed the string to contain only ASCII characters. If you want to support Unicode as well, then you may want to use [`Character.isUpperCase(int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Character.html#isUpperCase(int)) or [`Character.isLowerCase(int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Character.html#isLowerCase(int)).